# Does FirebasePagingAdapter load all data at once or load the data based on the page size?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

The [documentation](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/) is not clear whether it is loading all data at once or it is just loading the necessary page that is going to be loaded. I thought it was loading the necessary page data until I came across one of the YouTube comment saying that it is loading all of the data at once. I've tried monitoring the debugger but I still have doubt.

Answer (score 3):

According to docs you link. It just loading the necessary page

> The FirestorePagingAdapter listens for scrolling events and loads additional pages from the database only when needed.

Comment: In case you're curious, here's the code that limits the number of initial results retrieved: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/paging/FirestoreDataSource.java#L71, and here's the code for the subsequent pages: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/paging/FirestoreDataSource.java#L107. Yay for open-source. :)

Comment: thanks! I've read the sentence, and I have tried to understand the code. maybe it sounds dumb but the comment in YouTube I am referring to has 4 likes (in contrast with other comment with only 1 likes). It made me doubt my understanding of the documentation because I'm new to programming in general.

Comment: @DiskyAriaJetmiko Simply ignore those 4 likes ;)